# Delete group/id from a dataframe in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a datafame as such:

```
#Load the required libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Create data_set
data_set = {'id': [1, 
                   1,
                   1, 
                   1,
                   1,

                   2,
                   2,
                   2, 
                   2,
                   2,
                   2,
                   2,
                   2,
                   
                   3,
                   3,
                   3, 
                   3,
                   3,
                   3,
                   3,

                   4,
                   4,
                   4,
                   
                   ],
            'cycle': [1,
                      2,
                      3, 
                      4,
                      5,

                      1,
                      2,
                      3, 
                      4,
                      5,
                      6,
                      7,
                      8,

                      1,
                      2,
                      3, 
                      4,
                      5,
                      6,
                      7,

                      1,
                      2,
                      3,

                      ],
            
            'Salary': [10,
                       20,
                       30, 
                       40,
                       50,

                       10,
                       20,
                       30, 
                       40,
                       50,
                       60,
                       70,
                       10,

                       10,
                       20,
                       30, 
                       40,
                       50,
                       10,
                       80,

                       60,
                       70,
                       10,

                       ],
             'Expenditure': [100,
                             210,
                             320,
                             430,
                             540,

                             90,
                             200,
                             310,
                             420,
                             530,
                             100,
                             200,
                             300,

                             80,
                             190,
                             300,
                             410,
                             520,
                             340,
                             780,

                             100,
                             200,
                             300,
                             ],
            
               }

#Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data_set)
print("\n df = \n",df)
```

The above data frame looks as such:

[image]

Here id=1 appears 5 times.

Likewise id=2 appears 8 times; id=3 appears 7 times; id=4 appears 3 times

Now, I wish to delete, all the rows from id=2; and id=4.

The result in the dataframe appears such:

[image]

Can somebody please let me know how to achieve this task in Python?

Comment: `out = df[~df['id'].isin([2, 4])]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would `new_df = df[(df['id'] != 2) & (df['id'] != 4)]` do what you need?